# How can I pass data from one view to another in gluon mobile? how to switch to view and set Value?

Tags: javafx, gluon

I have a View1 with a Textfield1 and a Button. When i click a Button, i want to go to View 2 and set that Value to Textfield2 in View2. When i make it it go open a new Scene.

This is the Code to pass the Value:

```
charmListView.selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection,    
newSelection) -> {
        if (newSelection != null) {
            ModellList l = new ModellList();
            charmListView.selectedItemProperty().get().getName();
               l.setName(charmListView.selectedItemProperty()
  .get().getName());
            SucheFahrtPresenter s = new SucheFahrtPresenter();

              MobileApplication.getInstance()
.switchView(SUCHEFAHRT_VIEW);
s.setDP(l.getName());


        }
    });
```

I have this error:

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"        
 java.lang.NullPointerException

 at com.gluonapplication.views.SucheFahrtPresenter.setDP(SucheFahrtPresenter.java:122)
at com.gluonapplication.views.BasicView$3.lambda$run$0(BasicView.java:119)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.CharmListView.setSelectedItem(SourceFile:710)
```

I try the Second Solution like that:

That is the Second Presenter:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Inject
private Model model; 

public void initialize() {
         ........
    second.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            DP.setText(model.getText());
        }
    });
}
```

That is for the First presenter:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Inject
private Model model;

@FXML
public void test() {
    charmListView.selectedItemProperty().
    addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
        if (newSelection != null) {
            ModellList l = new ModellList();
            charmListView.selectedItemProperty().get().getName();
            l.setName(charmListView.selectedItemProperty().
    get().getName());
            SucheFahrtPresenter s = new SucheFahrtPresenter();
            model.setText(l.getName());
            MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(SUCHEFAHRT_VIEW);

        }
    });
}
```

These are my dependencies in Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.40.12'
    compile  'de.jensd:fontawesomefx:8.9'
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'
    androidCompile 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4'
    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.15.1'
    compile group: 'org.sqldroid', name: 'sqldroid', version: '1.0.3'   
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-desktop', version:    
   '0.0.2'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-common', version: 
  '0.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-android', version:  
  '0.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.airhacks', name: 'afterburner.fx', version: '1.7.0'   
 }
```

This is the issue I have:

[image]

After change the Code for Charmlistview . I have this Error

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gluonapplication.views.SucheFahrtPresenter.lambda$setDP$4(SucheFahrtPresenter.java:138)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View.c(SourceFile:1158)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the Gluon templates Project MultiView with FXML and Afterburner, or the Glisten-Afterburner one. Either of them will allow you using injection and getting a valid instance of the presenters.

*Solution 1. Glisten-Afterburner*

Using the Glisten-Afterburner default template, I've added two TextField controls, one to each of the views.

The only thing you need is exposing a method to set the value on the second presenter:

```
public class SecondaryPresenter extends GluonPresenter<YourApp> {

    @FXML
    private View secondary;

    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    public void initialize() {
        ...
    }

    public void setText(String value) {
        textField.setText(value);
    }
}
```

And in your first view, in the button event handler you can switch the view and set the text:

```
public class PrimaryPresenter extends GluonPresenter<YourApp> {

    @FXML
    private View primary;

    @FXML
    private CharmListView<String, String> charmListView;

    public void initialize() {
        charmListView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four"));
        charmListView.selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
            AppViewManager.SECONDARY_VIEW.switchView()
                .ifPresent(presenter -> 
            ((SecondaryPresenter) presenter).setText(nv));
        });
        ...
    }

}
```

This solution requires Gluon IDE plugin 2.5.0

*Solution 2. MultiView*

Alternatively you can use the MultiView with FXML and Afterburner template and create a Model class:

```
public class Model {

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public final void setText(String value) { text.set(value); }
    public final String getText() { return text.get(); }
    public final StringProperty textProperty() { return text; }

}
```

that you can inject in both presenters:

```
public class PrimaryPresenter {

    @FXML
    private View primary;

    @FXML
    private CharmListView<String, String> charmListView;

    @Inject
    private Model model;

    public void initialize() {
        charmListView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four"));
        charmListView.selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
            model.setText(nv);
            MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(SECONDARY_VIEW);
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class SecondaryPresenter {

    @FXML
    private View secondary;

    @FXML
    private TextField textField;

    @Inject
    private Model model;

    public void initialize() {
        secondary.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                ...
                textField.setText(model.getText());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: pereda Thank for the Answers. Is Glisten-Afterburner one already in  Gluon Mobile 4.0.0 . I have use Gluon Plugin 2.4.0.

Comment: Do you know how to have the Update for 2.5.0 on Eclipse IDE. 2.4.0 is available but not 2.5.0

Comment: I'm afraid Eclipse plugin 2.5.0 is not released yet. You can find it on NetBeans and IntelliJ.

Comment: I've edited my answer, adding a solution based on the MultiView template that you can find on your current plugin

Comment: Pereda. I try the Second Solution but it not works. I update my Post. Can you look how i code it? Maybe there is some Error. Thank for you help in advance

Comment: pereda. I use here in my Case in the First View a Charm List. When i click a charmlist i want to set the Value where i clicked in the Second View in a Textfield

Comment: I've edited my answer, adding a CharmListView instead of a TextField in the first View. Notice the wrong Charm Down dependencies (quite outdated).

Comment: Thanks for Answers .with  model.setText(nv)  i have a Nullpointer Exception. I notice that @Inject come for import javax.inject.Inject;. It is Right?

Comment: I can't say why without the stacktrace of that exception, but just in case replace it with: `if (nv != null) { model.setText(nv); }`, and try again.

Comment: I have update the Post and Post the stacktrace of the Exception. I try that too if (nv != null) { model.setText(nv); }. But it not works. It is like the @Inject
 private Model model; it don't works as well

Comment: use Afterburner template  means use that like so @Inject
 private Model model? I am not sure if i unterstand it very well.

Comment: Take the time to create a new project with the MultiView+FXML+Afterburner template, add the code I've posted, make sure it works, and then try to update your project.

Comment: It works now Fine. I use MultiView+FXML+Afterburner template. Works fine Now

Comment: @JoséPereda Hi! Is it OK to borrow this thread to ask a question about the afterburner? have added `...extends GluonPresenter<JWiFiLoggerApp> {` but I got the error `GluonPresenter cannot be resolved to a type`. Why? Yes. I have Afterburner included and Gluon Plugin 2.6.0.

Comment: No, it is not ok. This is not a chat :)

Comment: @JoséPereda Ok. Created a new question then.